# Batch file: sorting folders and files alphabetically

Tags: batch-file, alphabetical-sort

The batch file below recursively echos files and folders while adding some simple formatting, such as indenting to show the recursion depth, adding "/ " before folder names, "*" before certain files, and skipping folders named "Archive". It works great except that files and folders are sorted randomly, rather than alphabetically. How could this be changed to sort both files and folders alphabetically?

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1
set "tab=   "
set "indent="
call :run
exit /b

:run

REM echo the root folder name
for %%F in (.) do echo %%~fF
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------

set "folderBullet=\"
set "fileBullet=*"

:listFolder
setlocal

REM echo the files in the folder
for %%F in (*.txt *.pdf *.doc* *.xls*) do echo %indent%%fileBullet% %%F  -  %%~tF

REM loop through the folders
for /d %%F in (*) do (

  REM skip "Archive" folder
  if /i not "%%F"=="Archive" (

  REM if in "Issued" folder change the file bullet
  if /i "%%F"=="Issued" set "fileBullet= "

  echo %indent%%folderBullet% %%F
  pushd "%%F"
  set "indent=%indent%%tab%"
  call :listFolder

  REM if leaving "Issued folder change fileBullet
  if /i "%%F"=="Issued" set "fileBullet=*"

  popd
))
exit /b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very little change required. Convert FOR loops to FOR /F running sorted DIR commands. The `/A-D` option lists files only, and `/AD` lists directories only.

This version sorts files by name

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1
set "tab=   "
set "indent="
call :run
exit /b

:run

REM echo the root folder name
for %%F in (.) do echo %%~fF
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------

set "folderBullet=\"
set "fileBullet=*"

:listFolder
setlocal

REM echo the files in the folder
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d /one *.txt *.pdf *.doc* *.xls* 2^>nul'
) do echo %indent%%fileBullet% %%F  -  %%~tF

REM loop through the folders
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /one 2^>nul') do (

  REM skip "Archive" folder
  if /i not "%%F"=="Archive" (

  REM if in "Issued" folder change the file bullet
  if /i "%%F"=="Issued" set "fileBullet= "

  echo %indent%%folderBullet% %%F
  pushd "%%F"
  set "indent=%indent%%tab%"
  call :listFolder

  REM if leaving "Issued folder change fileBullet
  if /i "%%F"=="Issued" set "fileBullet=*"

  popd
))
exit /b
```

To sort by extension first, then by name, simply change `/ONE` to `/OEN`.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your `for /d` loop from

```
for /d %%F in (*) do
```

to

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o:n *.') do
```

and see whether that makes a difference.  Actually, ordering by name is the default behavior for `dir`, so you could probably get away with

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b *.') do
```

If some of your directory names have dots in them, you'll need to change it a little.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b') do (
    rem Is this a directory?
    if exist "%%F\" (
        rem do your worst....
    )
)
```